# Apache won't recognize Php 5.3.29 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, drupal-6, php-5.3

I have struggled to make Apache recognize Php 5.3.29 (I need it to run a very old Drupal 6 website).

I am using a Google Cloud Platform VM running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I successfully installed PHP 5.3.29 by compiling it and now running

```
# php -v
```

shows The correct version PHP 5.3.29. However after installing Apache I couldn't get it to recognize that version of PHP, it couldn't even compile PHP.

So I read somewhere that I need to run

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

But when i do that and run an info.php file with

```
<?php
phpinfo()
?>
```

I get PHP Version 5.5.12-2ubuntu4.4

My question is: How can I make it so Apache will point/recognize The older PHP version 5.3.29 ?

Comment: *PHP 5.3.29 by compiling* use config with apxs

Comment: @donald123 care to develop ? or maybe you can provide me with a similar case ?

Answer (score 0):

When you compile php from tarball

```
./configure \
      --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2  //path to your apxs2 file
    //... more config options

 make
 make test
 make install
```

After that simple resatart apache

Comment: What can the content of the apxs2 file be in that case ? I'm really not accustomed to this sort of configuration and I'm a bit lost.